# Join two dataframes tables applying condition on similar values of multiple column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I have the following two dataframes with different size.

```
df1: (with 40,000 data)
Date Latitude Longitude Car_Accident
2/10/22 43.69  -79.4     40
2/10/22 43.69  -79.4    34
2/20/22 43.68  -79.0     30
2/20/22 43.50  -79.1     35
............................
..............................

df2: (with 20,000 data)
Date Latitude Longitude Route
2/20/22 43.68  -79.0     111
2/20/22 43.50  -79.1    123
2/10/22 43.69  -79.4     124
2/10/22 43.69  -79.4     124
............................
.............................
```

***I want to merge them applying condition on three different columns.***

**if the value of df1['Date']==df2['Date'] & df1[Latitude]==df2[Latitude] & df1[Longitude]==df2[Longitude]**

#### then we will add the column with having data who satisfied this condition

#### Example

```
final df:

Date   Latitude Longitude  Car_Accident  Route

2/20/22 43.50    -79.1            35      123
2/20/22 43.68    -79.0            30       111
2/10/22 43.69    -79.4            40       124
2/10/22 43.69    -79.4            34       124
```

#### Method I tried:

I tried inner join as well as indexing. Sometimes I had memory error, sometimes it gives null table or left table if I use left join.`pandas.merge(df1, df2, on=[Date,Lat,Long]) or dataframe.merge`anything is not giving proper answer.

***Problem I faced:***

In inner join cartesian product is consuming huge computation process and also I don't is this the right method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) right after the left merge should give you the result you're looking for:

```
final_df= (
            df1.merge(df2, on=["Date", "Latitude", "Longitude"], how="left")
               .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
           )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(final_df)

      Date  Latitude  Longitude  Car_Accident  Route
0  2/10/22     43.69      -79.4            40    124
1  2/10/22     43.69      -79.4            34    124
2  2/20/22     43.68      -79.0            30    111
3  2/20/22     43.50      -79.1            35    123
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That's the thing I wanted. Many thanks